# Hide navigationBar, Show navigationBar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

I met with a problem. At first some code from AppDelegate.

```
 - (void)HideMainNavigationBar{
navigCtrl.navigationBarHidden = YES;
}

- (void)ShowMainNavigationBar{
navigCtrl.navigationBarHidden = NO;
}
```

navigCtrl is my navigation controller.
In my other View Controller I need hide my navigationBar and then show it, to display it correctly.

```
- (void) moviePlayerWillExitFullScreen:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"exitfullscreen");
   AppDelegate *ptr = [AppDelegate SharedAppDelegate];
   [ptr HideMainNavigationBar];
   [ptr ShowMainNavigationBar];
}
```

After that, instead of my custom tabBarButton I saw Back button:

[image]

After tap ob Back button, it disappears, and I see my navigationBar again with my custom button. This 'bug' was detected in iOS 5.1, on iOS 4.3.2 everithing is ok.

This makes me crazy, help please.

P.S. I know, that I can use:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
```

to display navigationBar correctly, but i need to show/hide navigationBar to hide it, while rotating VideoPlayer.

Any ideas?
Wait your answers, thanks.

Comment: If it must be hidden all the time, did you try to hide it in viewWillAppear ?

Comment: It must be hidden when moviePlayer is in fullscreen mode, because I see it during rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some manipulations I decided simply to set alpha to my navigationBar.

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"5"))  
            [ptr HideMainNavigationBar];
else self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0;
```

I hope it would be useful for someone. See ya.

Answer (score -1):

I just have posted code dedicated on UINavigationBar appearance management on github. check out [RRViewControllerExtension](https://github.com/Roen-Ro/RRViewControllerExtension), it will solve your problem gracefully.